# unexpected result converting date using datestr

Tags: matlab

Can anyone tell me why if I type in MATLAB

```
datestr('17-03-2016','dd-mmmm-yyyy')
```

I get

```
06-September-0022
```

Comment: `datestr` internally uses `datenum`, same behaviour with `datestr(datenum('17-03-2016'))`. Unable to understand it.

Comment: try this instead datetime('17-03-2016','Format','dd-mmmm-yyyy')

Comment: @Daniel It's true, but I still feel Matlab made a mistake, datestr(datenum('17-03-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') ) would work fine, while datenum('17-03-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') does not, despite specifying the format - even their example seems to be outputting the correct answers (while mine is not version 2010b)

Comment: @Daniel, I wrote an answer but long story short, it treats the input as `0017-03-2016`, which is an invalid date, but with some slack it becomes (2016 - 31) = 1985 days after `0017-03-31`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:  `datestr(datenum('17-03-2016','dd-mmmm-yyyy'))`

Answer (score 5):

From the [`datestr` docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html)

> DateString = datestr(___,formatOut) specifies the format of the output text using formatOut. You can use formatOut with any of the input arguments in the above syntaxes.

So in your example the `'dd-mmmm-yyyy'` is specifying the *output* format, not the input format.

Also

> DateString = datestr(DateStringIn) converts DateStringIn to text in the format, day-month-year hour:minute:second. All dates and times represented in DateStringIn must have the same format.

where

[image]

`'dd-mm-yyyy'`  is ***not*** in the list of allowed `DateStringIn` formats *AND* the documentation explicitly recommends using `datenum` to ensure correct behaviour. (Note: I underlined the wrong *must* in the sentence, it's the second *must* I wanted to emphasise)

So [Sandar_Usama's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37964818/1011724) answer of

```
datestr(datenum('17-03-2016','dd-mmmm-yyyy'))
```

is the officially correct method straight out of the docs.

Bottom line, always read the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

To address the last unanswered point in this question, why does `datenum` behave like this?

```
>> datestr(datenum('17-03-2016'))

ans =

06-Sep-0022
```

Without explicitly telling `datestr` and `datenum` how it should treat the input, it will try to match against the expected formats. Since none of the documented formats match (see [@dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011724/dan)'s answer), it fails.

Although what it does next is undocumented, at least up to whatever version of Matlab we are running, it falls into a "last resource" attempt to give you a date number.

Matlab will try to parse different month names from your input, remove non-numeric characters, and then timedate elements from the string. In your case, they are `17`, `03`, and `2016`. The first is expected to be either month or year. Since there's no 17th month, it is treated as year. Then `03` is the month, and `2016` is the day.

Now, March 2016th, 17 is not a valid date, but Matlab will give it a slack and read as 1985 days past March 31st, 17. And that gives us September 6th, 22.

Because Matlab's timestamp is a floating number for the number of days since its epoch, you can trigger that answer, using valid dates, like so:

```
>> datestr(datenum('0017-03-31') + 1985)

ans =

06-Sep-0022
```